# Exploding input from text area and looping through 2 arrays

Tags: php, sql

I'm entering a list of numbers in two text areas. One area is known as SectionID and the other Length. Both are of equal length. I'm submitting these to a PHP handling page which enter details to an SQL db.

```
<?PHP
$exchange = $_POST['Exchange'];
$estimate = $_POST['Estimate'];
$sectionid = $_POST['SectionID'];
$length = $_POST['Length'];

$username = "USER";
$password = "PASS";
$hostname = "HOST";

$con = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
$selected = mysql_select_db("DATAB", $con) or die("Could not select examples");

$sectionid = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $sectionid));
$length = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $length));

foreach ($sectionid as $key => $secdata) { 
$lendata = $length[$key];
$query = "INSERT INTO table (Exchange, Estimate, SectionID, Length) VALUES ('$exchange','$estimate','$secdata','$lendata')"; 

if (!mysql_query($query,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
}
}
echo "$estimate created on $exchange Exchange!";

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

This for some reason isn't working and I just can't see my mistake. Never before have I had to do this. The current result makes 1 entry only to the db, leaves the SectionID blank and fills Length with multiple lines from the text area.

What I'm trying to achieve is create as many entries as there are SectionID's in the list and insert the SectionID and Length that correspond to each other. This is not my only attempt, I have used about4 different variations of exploding the $_POST.

Anyone care to help me out?

Comment: what happen when you echo the $query?

Comment: @kraysak Everything is as should be except $secdata, which is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem with explode or anything related to textarea value. its a SQL Syntax error

try this

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `table` (`Exchange`, `Estimate`, `SectionID`, `Length`) VALUES('$exchange','$estimate','$secdata','$lendata')";
```

you may enable php error display now.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. This was partly the answer to my problem. My var `$sectionid = $_POST['SectionID'];` should have been `$sectionid = $_POST['sectionID'];` It was a Name mismatch between my form and the script

Answer (score 0):

To debug your code, try

```
print_r($sectionid);
foreach ($sectionid as $key => $secdata) { 
$lendata = $length[$key];
print '<br />row '.$key . ':{'.$secdata.'}';
$query = "INSERT INTO table (Exchange, Estimate, SectionID, Length) VALUES ('$exchange','$estimate','$secdata','$lendata')"; 

if (!mysql_query($query,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
}
}
```

If the data is being received and parsed correctly, you should see on your screen the initial array printed to the screen along with each variable within the array printed on seperate lines surrounded by brackets.

If you see something like

row 0: {}

Then it means you arent parsing or receiving the data correctly. Check that you are posting sectionID and not sectionid (upper/lower variance with the "id" part).

Comment: This was also a problem reference the upper/lower of the S.